# result are showing empty "AND" query and with left joing

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    j.* , 
    month(j.create_date) as month 
FROM tbl_jobs AS j 
LEFT JOIN tbl_well_data AS wd 
    on j.id = wd.job_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_well_depth AS wdp 
    on j.id = wdp.job_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_well_formation AS wf 
    on j.id = wf.job_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_well_tubing_size AS wts 
    on j.id = wts.job_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pumping AS p 
    on j.id = p.job_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pumping_puid AS pf 
    on j.id = pf.job_id 
WHERE j.create_date >= '2013-04-01' 
AND j.create_date <= '2013-04-25' 
AND ( pf.puid_id = 109 AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 AND pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 ) 
AND ( pf.puid_id = 112 AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 AND pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 ) 
AND FIND_IN_SET('1',j.services)
```

Problem with query while using multiple `AND` result are showing empty  when I am using this result will appear but I want `pf.puid_id = 112 AND pf.puid_id = 109` accordingly and these puid_id is preesent in my DB table so why this problem occur?

When I am using OR the results are showing on the basis of only on `pf.puid_id = 112` or  `pf.puid_id = 109`

Comment: Please format your query so that it's readable.

Comment: Can you show a sample row that you want displayed, but it doesn't get displayed?

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE j.create_date >= '2013-04-01' 
    AND j.create_date <= '2013-04-25' 
    AND (( pf.puid_id = 109 OR pf.puid_id = 112)
       AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 
       AND pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 )
    AND FIND_IN_SET('1',j.services)
```

Yes. Please use OR.

Comment: WHY use OR while all record present in db table and ID also present?

Comment: In a record, i meant one row of record, the puid_id can either be 109 OR 112, right? It can't be exist at the same time with a single row of record.

Answer (score 0):

When you use AND for both puid_id, mathematical logical states that you want BOTH CONDITIONS to be satisfied at the same time. That means that your query will only match rows that respect these two condition.s at the same time.

So you should ask yourself: how can a single thing be equal to two distinct things at the same time? That is what you are trying to do using AND.

Using OR will give you rows that match at least one of the conditions given (in this case that is impossible for both conditions to be satisfied).

Consider reading more basic concepts before going any further. It will increase your software quality.

Hope I helped.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks :) but requirement was different that's why ok i will read and find an other solution but thanks for ur help i didn't think about how both condition can be true for ONE COLUMN at a time  OK THANKS

Comment: I talked about the condition for one column because you seemed not to be understanding it on the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
AND ( pf.puid_id = 109 AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 AND 
                             pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 ) 
AND ( pf.puid_id = 112 AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 AND 
                             pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 )
```

You are saying you want `pf.puid_id` to be equal to **both** 109 and 112 at the same time. I am sure you really mean that it should be **either** one of the two, not to have **both** values at the same time.

Replace those two lines with:

```
AND ( pf.puid_id IN (109,112) AND pf.volume BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 AND 
                             pf.corrosive = 1 AND pf.bh = 0 AND pf.ct = 1 )
```

When you are trying to test if a value is equal to one of the desired values, IN keyword is your friend. It makes the query shorter and more readable.

An example -- this condition:

```
WHERE id = 5 OR id = 8 OR id = 13 OR id = 21 OR id = 34
```

is the same as:

```
WHERE id IN (5,8,13,21,34)
```

Another suggestion. Replace:

```
j.create_date >= '2013-04-01' 
AND j.create_date <= '2013-04-25'
```

with:

```
j.create_date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-25'
```

Both are same and equally correct, but the second one is shorter and more readable.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please upvote and/or accept it.